# Is an ITO diffusion time slice always Normally distributed?

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

As the title says, if we take a time slice on any Ito diffusion - are we guaranteed that the data is always Normally distributed?

[image]

- This seems like a useful property for computer generalization and when the distribution of the forward propagation is hard to solve.

Note: My question does not include fractal diffusion.

Comment: This seems trivially false since Ito diffusions are closed under "nice" functions (like the conditions of Ito's lemma, say). So if $X_t$ is a Brownian motion (therefore an Ito process), then $Y_t = e^{X_t}$ is also an Ito process, and has lognormal distribution at a fixed time. Was there a particular reason you expected this to be always normal?

Comment: @ChrisHaug Thank you - that makes sense. The reason I ask is because I am writing a web-app and instead of transferring all the path data from one point to another - I wanted to return an array with mean and sd for each time index - which would be much smaller in size.

Comment: @ChrisHaug A numerical schema for the forward kolmogorov would be helpful too if one exists.